# Complex integral $1/(z^2+1)$ along unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to compute the complex integral $$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz$$

both i and -i lie on c , what can I do ? I tried caushy , series , i used def of contour integral along  c = z(t)=exp(it) and it gave me zero .

Comment: How do you define such an integral?

Comment: Integration of f(z) along c = integration of f(z(t))d(z(t)) where z(t) is parametrization of c

Comment: I meant how do you define the integral when it passes through a singularity?

Comment: I don't know . In def I just wrote , f needs to be piecewise continuous on c .

Comment: I understand the usual definitions, that is not what I am asking. I am asking what you expect the above integral to mean when you are integrating over a path that passes through a singularity?

Comment: I understand what you're asking , but I thought that we may use the usual def .If I knew what you're asking , I wouldn't ask the question.

Comment: You could try changing the path slightly. Integrate along $|z|=1$, except when near $z=\pm i $. When near those points, deform that part of the path into a small semicircle that would enclose the poles. In other words, have a small "bump". Then let it's radius tend to zero, and you can apply the Residue theorem. Also, make all of this formal, I'm just giving you hand-wavy hints, I'm in a hurry ;)

Comment: Well, f is not piecewise continuous on c, so the natural result in your definition is: undefined. I do not see why deforming the path would be a valid solution since the result then depends upon how the path is deformed, even in the limit.

Comment: @LeBtz: do you think that the answer "infinity" is more accurate than "undefined"?

Comment: @SamarHayek I provided an answer in terms of a Cauchy Principal Value interpretation of the integral of interest.  There are some details that are embedded, so please let me know how I can improve the answer.  The precise description I gave for the contour deformation of a circle with circular indentations is perhaps more than needed here.  But I wanted to retain rigor and precision.  As always, I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @Dr.MV I'm taking this complex analysis course . Unfortunately , i've no idea what's " caushy principal value .. " . But thnx for ur answer , i'm trying to understand it.

Comment: @SamarHayek A CPV is a way of interpreting an improper integral that does not converge in the classical sense.  Here is a Wikipedia link - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value.

Comment: In any attempt to *use* a value for a divergent integral, you should be careful.

Answer (score 2):

The integral is improper but can be defined it terms of a Cauchy Principal Value interpretation.

Define the deformed integration contour $C$ as comprised of the circle $|z|=1$ with (approximately) semi-circular indentations $C^{\pm}_{\epsilon}$ of radius $\epsilon$ around the points $z=\pm i$, respectively, such that the singularities are excluded.

By the residue theorem, we have

$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{z^2+1}=0$$

But, we also have that

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{dz}{z^2+1}&=\lim_{\gamma \to 0} \left(\int_{-\pi/2+\gamma}^{\pi/2-\gamma}\frac{ie^{i\theta}d\theta}{e^{i2\theta}+1}+\int_{\pi/2+\gamma}^{3\pi/2-\gamma}\frac{ie^{i\theta}d\theta}{e^{i2\theta}+1}\right)\\\\
&+\int_{C^+_{\epsilon}}\frac{dz}{z^2+1}+\int_{C^-_{\epsilon}}\frac{dz}{z^2+1}
\end{align}$$

where $\gamma$ is the angle such that $\epsilon=2\sin(\gamma/2)\approx \gamma$ for small $\gamma$.

The final step consists of evaluating the integrals around $C^{\pm}_{\epsilon}$.  So, let's examine the integral around $C^{+}_{\epsilon}$.

First note that $\frac{1}{z^2+1}=\frac{1/2i}{z-i}-\frac{1/2i}{z+i}$.  Then,
parameterize $z$ as $z=i+\epsilon e^{i\phi}$ so that $dz=ie^{i\phi}d\phi$ and $\phi$ goes from $\arccos(\epsilon/2)-\pi/2\approx. 0$ to $-\arccos(\epsilon/2)-\pi/2\approx. -\pi$ (where the approximations are for small $\epsilon$).  Thus, we have

$$\lim_{\gamma \to 0}\int_{C^+_{\epsilon}}\frac{dz}{z^2+1}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{0}^{-\pi}\left(\frac{1/2i}{\epsilon e^{i\phi}}-\frac{1/2i}{2i+\epsilon e^{i\phi}}\right)i\epsilon e^{i\phi}d\phi=-\pi/2.$$

The opposite result holds for the integral around $C^{-}_{\epsilon}$.  Putting this all together reveals that

$$\lim_{\gamma \to 0} \left(\int_{-\pi/2+\gamma}^{\pi/2-\gamma}\frac{ie^{i\theta}d\theta}{e^{i2\theta}+1}+\int_{\pi/2+\gamma}^{3\pi/2-\gamma}\frac{ie^{i\theta}d\theta}{e^{i2\theta}+1}\right)=0$$

which is the Cauchy Principal Value interpretation of the improper integral of interest!

---

**NOTE 1**:

We can directly show that

$$\lim_{\gamma \to 0} \left(\int_{-\pi/2+\gamma}^{\pi/2-\gamma}\frac{ie^{i\theta}d\theta}{e^{i2\theta}+1}+\int_{\pi/2+\gamma}^{3\pi/2-\gamma}\frac{ie^{i\theta}d\theta}{e^{i2\theta}+1}\right)=i\lim_{\gamma \to 0} \left(\int_{-\pi/2+\gamma}^{\pi/2-\gamma}\sec \theta d\theta+\int_{\pi/2+\gamma}^{3\pi/2-\gamma}\sec \theta d\theta\right)=0$$

by using $\int \sec \theta d\theta=\log|\sec \theta + \tan \theta|$

---

**NOTE 2**:

The integral $\oint_C \frac{1}{z^2+1}dz$ can easily be shown to be zero when $C$ is a contour that is inside $|z|=1$ since there are no poles enclosed.

Interestingly, the integral $\oint_C \frac{1}{z^2+1}dz$ can also be shown to be zero if $C$ is a contour that embeds $|z|=1$ since the sum of the two residues are $\frac{1}{2i}$ and $\frac{-1}{2i}$.

Comment: Not to be too nitpicky but don't your limits/variables mismatch? Shouldn't you replace $z$ by $e^{i\theta}$ to have those limits of integration?

Comment: @CameronWilliams You're correct.  But I was conserving space.  What would you suggest?  I could replace with $C-C^+-C^-$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I edited accordingly.  Thanks for the suggestion.